# Hosting an online course with WebRTC

Tags: html, webrtc

WebRTC has performance issues once you get up to a certain amount of people in a video conference, but if you had no video, could you host 100 people or more?

The challenge, I'm trying to solve is live streaming with pure HTML5.

Comment: have you looked into using Selective Forwarding Units(SFU)?

Comment: Didn't know about 'em, thanks!

Comment: check this out http://www.dialogic.com/~/media/products/docs/Putting-WebRTC-Media-in-the-Cloud